# Detect that AWS Elastic deployment failed

Tags: detection, alarm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can we **detect** that AWS ElasticBeanstalk (**EB**) deployment failed?

When deployment fails, the EB environment is green and we think that everything is OK. But it's not. The app is not running.

If we go to logs `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/11170e07ae99-stdouterr.log` we can see that there is an error. **How can we detect it** so that we can send it to Slack or other tools?

#### Possible solutions

- ping the servers but it's not very reliable since a EB will revert to its previous deployment
- https://marbot.io/ but I didn't manage to run it
- can cloudwatch help us?

Comment: just setup a notification(SNS) on deploy errors

Comment: @NeverBe but how do you detect a deploy error happened?

Comment: it's not me, its EB. errors in the scripts. If no errors, it can be checked using healthcheck (must be configure) + deploys based on healthcheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to setup email notifications about "notable events" (which should include deployment errors): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.sns.html

If prefer Slack notification, you can just use Slack's [Email app](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/206819278-send-emails-to-slack)